# why the added html in code is not the same as in reality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code

```
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var iiDiv = document.createElement('div') $(iiDiv).addClass("form-group") var iLabel = document.createElement('label');
    $(iiDiv).append("<label for=\"timeslot\" class=\"p-label-required\">Time Slot</label>");
    $(iLabel).addClass("input-group p-has-icon p-custom-arrow");
    $(iLabel).append("<select id=\"timeslot\" name=\"timeslot\" required=\"required\" class=\"form-control\" >");
    $(iLabel).append("<option class=\"p-select-default\" value=\"\">Select value</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"1\">1</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"2\">2</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"3\">3</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"4\">4</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"5\">5</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"6\">6</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"7\">7</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"8\">8</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"9\">9</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"10\">10</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"11\">11</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("<option value=\"12\">12</option>");
    $(iLabel).append("</select>");
    $(iLabel).append("<div class=\"p-field-cb\"></div>");
    $(iLabel).append(" <span class=\"p-select-arrow\"><i class=\"fa fa-caret-down\"></i></span>");
    $(iLabel).append("<span class=\"input-group-icon\"><i class=\"fa fa-cutlery\"></i></span>");
    $(iiDiv).append(iLabel) $("#numberOfTableDiv").append(iiDiv);
}
```

as you see, i'm adding some options **inside** the `select`, but look at the generated html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="timeslot" class="p-label-required">Time Slot</label>
    <label class="input-group p-has-icon p-custom-arrow">
        <select id="timeslot" name="timeslot" required="required" class="form-control"></select>
        <option class="p-select-default" value="">Select value</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <div class="p-field-cb"></div> <span class="p-select-arrow"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span><span class="input-group-icon"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i></span></label>
</div>
```

the options are going out of the select

Comment: because your options are not appending in `select` tag but instead iLabel.  recommending to do something like this $('select').append( options)

Comment: If you did that all as string concatenation it would work. Appending elements though must be complete elements .... not append a start tag...then some inner content ...then end tag. The DOM is not like a text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var mySelect = $("<select id=\"timeslot\" name=\"timeslot\" required=\"required\" class=\"form-control\" >");
mySelect.append("<option value=\"1\">1</option>");
//...
$(iLabel).append(mySelect);
```

The issue was that jQuery appends elements, not actual HTML. This might sound like the *same*, but the difference is that each element appended is attached to the DOM *before* any other element is appended. The result is that the select element is added to the document, and *then* any other element is added to `iLabel`, rather than the select, because there is no HTML being interpreted, just elements in the DOM.

Comment: where is my mistake? i didn't close the select before ading the options